# android music player get last played list

Tags: java, android, service, audio-player, android-music-player

I am sorry if this question is already asked, I can't find keyword for this.
I am currently building a music streaming app. I have a problem in the playback.
So in order to remember the next song to be played, I started the music service and send an arraylist of the musics and the current position that need to be played.

```
activity.stopService(new Intent(activity, MusicService.class));
activity.startService(new Intent(activity, MusicService.class).putExtra("list", data)
                        .putExtra("position", position));
```

I have a small space in the whole app showing now playing music. It's worked great except when I restarted my phone which means the service is destroyed and the app does not remember the last played list.

I am currently thinking about creating a local database to remember the last played list. But I think it is not the best practice for this. Can someone give me a way to achieve what I need? thank you!

EDIT:
I ended up converting arraylist to JSON and save in SharedPreference. Next time I need it, I convert it back to arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

I myself created a music player app for android , and what i did to save last played song list is following -

1. Created a **Hashmap** with song id as key and position in list as value
2. Update this Hashmap whenever song is played .
3. At last ,  save this Hashmap in internal memory of device .

Code to save Hashmap in internal memory -

```
 File Listdirectory = cw.getDir("your direcotry", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File ListPath = new File(Listdirectory,"file name");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fMap = new FileOutputStream(ListPath);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(fMap);
        s.writeObject(your hashmap);
        s.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called, "Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! ": https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()